# can we build for Symbian^3 same code done in s60 3rd edition using lwuit

Tags: java-me, symbian, compatibility, lwuit

I have made application in j2me using lwuit and successfully built on S60 3d edition FP2, now to make wide compatibility i want to make build for Symbian^3, so is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah its possible. Because LWUIT supports both touch and non touch mobiles and no need to change the code for this. AFAIK you have to check following steps,

- **Resolution:** Because resolution of symbian s60 3rd edition not more than 240x320 or 320x240. But symbian^3 smartphone having 640x360 or 360x640.
- **MenuBar:** [Look on this blog](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2009/11/optimized-for-touch.html)
- **Drag and Drop:** You can enable drag and drop the components If you needs.

Just test the LWUITDemo application from repository on symbian s60 3rd editon and symbian^3 mobiles. Then you can find the what are all the changes have to do. Also look on this [wiki information about Symbian.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbian)

Comment: And you can use Nokia RDA to test your jar file on lots of different phones: https://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the same jar file on the Symbian^3 devices, unless some of the APIs have changed. At least this was true for S60 5th edition, I've never used j2me on Symbian^3 myself.